# add font to drop down menu

Tags: android, kotlin

is there any way to add font and text size to dropDownMenu ?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/sortByWatchList"
    android:title="@string/watch_list_menu_text" />
<item 
    android:id="@+id/sortByLatest"
    android:title="@string/latest_menu_text" />
```

Comment: If it's a _PopUpMenu_ then you can create custom style and write font and text size and apply style to popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

refer this code,

menu_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:text="Menu 1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:text="Menu 2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView" />
```

class file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun buttonClick(view: View) {
    val layoutInflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val popupView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null)
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(
        popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true)
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(PopupWindow.OnDismissListener {
        //add code 
    })

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view)


}}
```